# Android tablet apps using phonegap?

Tags: cordova, android

I'm newbie to android and present working on android smartphone apps using phonegap and we want to work on android tablets simultaneously. I want to know that can we use same code and procedure of android smartphone to tablet version or any difference in concepts. Can anyone help me by giving brief idea of how to start with tablet apps using phonegap and what the things or concepts should i remember while developing tablet apps? I hope my question is clear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds very possible using responsive layouts. Have you looked at Bootstrap by Twitter? Their responsive layouts are easy to use and will help you with your app. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

You may need to change the resolution in the Android Manifest if the resolution is too small on tablet compared to handset.

Also, css animations on newer Androids works pretty well, but is very choppy on older Androids. The Android tablet I own, Galaxy S, performs poorly for animations. This is due to the amount of visual memory it tries to animate. Tablets generally will perform slower for animations than handsets.

As far as your javascript logic, you shouldn't have any trouble porting it.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your response i will go through the link it might help me @gradecomplex